# Regex to add a word before an existing word in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, nodejs-stream, nodejs-server

Appreciate any help to write a nodejs regex.

First search for the exact words "ChildBucketOne" and "ChildBucketTwo" and add exact word ParentBucket before every occurence of ChildBucketOne or/and ChildBucketTwo.

I am trying to use one regex.

Input1: webApplication.ChildBucketOne
Input2: webApplication.ChildBucketTwo

Output: webApplication.ParentBucket.ChildBucket.ChildBucketOne

webApplication.ParentBucket.ChildBucket.ChildBucketTwo

Thanks!

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use String replace function of JavaScript

```
let input1 = 'webApplication.ChildBucketOne';
let input2 = 'webApplication.ChildBucketTwo';


function preprocess(input){

 return input.replace('.ChildBucket', '.ParentBucket.ChildBucket.ChildBucket');

}


console.log(preprocess(input1));
console.log(preprocess(input2));
```

Live in action - https://jsitor.com/IUb7cRtvf

Answer (score 1):

Node.js is basically the same as Javascript, except that it runs on the server.

Back to your question, below is the snippet to find **all occurrence** of `.ChildBucket`, and replace them by `.ParentBucket.ChildBucket`.

```js
const original = `
# dummy text 1
webApplication.ChildBucketOne
# dummy text 2
webApplication.ChildBucketTwo
# dummy text 3
`

console.log('--- Original ---')
console.log(original)

const replaced = original.replace(/\.ChildBucket/g, '.ParentBucket.ChildBucket')

console.log('--- Replaced ---')
console.log(replaced)
```

**Explanation**

You see that I use regular expression (i.e. `/\.ChildBucket/g`) instead of a string because the [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-TW/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function will only replace the first occurrence of the matching string by default. Using regular expression with the [`g` modifier](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_g.asp) will turn it into the global match, which replaces all the occurrence.

**Output**

```
--- Original ---
# dummy text 1
webApplication.ChildBucketOne
# dummy text 2
webApplication.ChildBucketTwo
# dummy text 3
--- Replaced ---
# dummy text 1
webApplication.ParentBucket.ChildBucketOne
# dummy text 2
webApplication.ParentBucket.ChildBucketTwo
# dummy text 3
```